# php: How to add image stored in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, css

I have stored different background images for different users in my database, now I want to display background image associated with that user, i.e. $user['background_pic'], how I can display background for each user in php using background-image property.

I referred to few stackoverflow similar questions, I am unable to understand how to give url in php to retrieve path.

Comment: What is your current code? How did you store the image?

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't a database, it's a php application to access a mysql database.

Comment: I used the same code I had for uploading profile picture, it stores picture in a directory and then update database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little fuzzy so my answer will be a little fuzzy too.  Assuming `$user['background_pic']` contains the working URL of the background picture, add this in PHP of your web page ...

```
...
<style>
  body { background-image: url("<?= $user['background_pic'] ?>"); }
</style>
...
```

When rendered, this will add some inline CSS styling to your web page HTML that will add the background image to the `body` of your web page.

Comment: Yes, It worked, Thanks a lot. I will work on question presentation next time.